# Can a steed provide cover while riding it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cover

If I cast *Greater Steed* and fly straight up directly over my foe, can I get a cover bonus to my AC if  the foe attacks me with a ranged weapon?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From PHB p196:

> Walls, trees, creatures, and other obstacles can provide cover during combat, making a target more difficult to harm. A target can benefit from cover only when an attack or other effect originates on the opposite side of the cover.

The steed certainly counts as a creature, and while you could squabble over the linguistics of the word "side" (having something between you and your attacker on the vertical axis instead of the horizontal one could arguably not count as a "side"), I think the written intent is clear. There is a horse between you and the thing trying to shoot you. Some amount of cover should be granted.

Comment: Would you say (or clarify) that it's only "opposite side" if the attacker is directly below and that offset would not?

Comment: I think one has to employ a little latitude here even when looking for a RAW answer. In terms of pure mathematics, any slightest offset would stop something from being truly "opposite". Cover comes half, three-quarters, and full. Angles and orientation will affect how much cover (if any) at the DM's ruling.